# How to check default-ipc-mode in docker (v18.09)

Tags: docker

Is there any way to check default-ipc-mode value in docker v18.09?

I have tried searching for it in:

```
1. docker info
2. /etc/docker
3. /etc/sysconfig/docker
4. /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
5. /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.docker
6. docker inspect <container>
```

Basically, after bringing up a test container on docker v18.09, I see this in 'df -h':

`shm 64M 0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/7b362d4438678b2e07c08d17e61d813dc85e2e49d1540c87e7c1ebe470052b95/mounts/shm`

My requirement is simple and trying to find a way to disable above shared-memory feature.

After digging further, looks like /dev/shm from the actual docker container is getting mounted on to the host.

What is the benefit or use from doing so?